# jQuery Add/Remove Class when Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create the following functionality with conditionals...

1. User scrolls down (120px for example) from the top of the screen, the HTML class 'state-nav-is-hidden' is added to the HTML tag.
2. When he gets to the BOTTOM after scrolling the class 'state-nav-is-visible' replaces the the HTML class above.
3. In addition, if the user scrolls and stops before the bottom, then scrolls back up 30px toward the top, 'state-nav-is-visible' replaces the hidden tag.

The following below ONLY accomplishes 1. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = $("html");
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        var lastScrollTop = 120;
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (st > lastScrollTop){
            header.removeClass("state-nav-is-visible").addClass('state-nav-is-hidden');
        } else {
            header.removeClass('state-nav-is-hidden').addClass("state-nav-is-visible");
        }        
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/V7Apa/ - what is missing?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm new to coding, but could you take a look and let me know if I'm off to the right start? I'm trying to add functionality for the "if scrolled to the bottom", and once I complete that I need to find a way that if it is scrolled 30 pixels from any current position it triggers also... Hope this makes sense? I'm more than happy to donate if you have a minute! :)

Comment: No need to donate. Did you see my fiddle in the comments? Your code already do that using `lastScrollTop`. What do you mean by "30 pixels from any current position it triggers also".

Comment: I need multiple conditions I think, I added some comments to here: http://jsfiddle.net/XAtPM/2/

Desired effect is: http://mailchimp.com/features/
This nav is similar to the new iOS update. 
1. User loads page, main menu is visible. (Complete)
2. If they scroll down, menu disappears via a class change after 120 pixels from the top. (Complete)
3. If they reach the bottom/END of screen/browser after scrolling, class is changed back to visible.
4. If the user stops to read throughout the page, if they decide to scroll toward the top again the menu reappears (just like in the

Comment: Once I achieve this effect, it will be shared with the community. The effect is similar to the new iPhone Safari navigation functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
st > lastScrollTop
```

is the right condition for 1.

```
st + $(window).height() === document.height
```

is the consition for 2.

I did not really get point 3, but you have to measure it. Open Chrome and a console as a separate window and type out the current status, like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    console.log("Top: " + $(this).scrollTop() + ", Bottom: " + ($(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height()));
});
```

and then watch the output as you scroll.

EDIT:

Taken into account the comments to the answer I have decided to take a closer look at the fiddle. I understand Mike States, as he wants to solve point 3, but unfortunately it is still unclear for me, but given the fact that he asks so nicely and so consistently for a solution to that problem, I have made a guess. Please, let me know if there is anything wrong with my guess. Everything was written based on your fiddle.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.wrapper {
    height:2000px
}
.state-nav-is-visible{
    background-color:red;
}
.state-nav-is-hidden{
    background-color:green;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = $("html");
    var reachedBottom = false;
    $(window).scroll(function(Event){
        var lastScroll = 120;

        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        //var bs = $(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight == $(document).height();

        if (st < lastScroll){
            header.removeClass('state-nav-is-hidden').addClass('state-nav-is-visible');
        } 
        else if (st + $(window).height() === document.height) {
            header.removeClass('state-nav-is-hidden');
            reachedBottom = true;
        } else if ((reachedBottom) && (st + $(window).height() <= document.height - 30)) {
            reachedBottom = false;
            console.log((st + $(window).height() - (document.height - 30)));
        }
/*
        else if (How do I get current position and if scrolled UP 30 PIXELS do something) {
            alert('test');
        }
*/
        else {
            header.addClass("state-nav-is-hidden");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think I am understanding a bit more. Thank you again, I'm a designer by trade.

It's important I get this working correctly. So it obviously works once I scroll down 120 from the top. The HTML class is changed from visible to hidden. I know I'm so close, but the moment you are scroll to the bottom of the page I want the nav to reappear by changing the now "Hidden" class back to "Visible". Mailchimp has the EXACT functionality that is needed, and they use this method. Once I'm done with when they scroll to the bottom, I also need it to work whenever they scroll up + 30 pixels it could change.

Comment: Basically, how do I write this in an if/else statement.
- IF the user scrolls down 120px from top
- IF the user scrolls to the end of the document/window
- IF the user scrolls up + 30 pixels

Please send Paypal info, you've been a lifesaver.

Comment: Mike, you can read two of the conditions in my answer, basically you will have to put those into if and else if conditions, read and try out the examples here (remember, it is better to teach somebody how to fish than giving him a fish, as you are feeding him for a lifetime in the former case): http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: Lajos, thanks for your help... What probably would take you 5 minutes took me HOURS to rearrange to work, but I got the functionality working. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/V7Apa/4/ I'm at a dead end though, is it possible to register the current scroll position and if SCROLLED UP 30 Pixels from that point, do something in addition to the other conditions? Also, is my approach a BEST PRACTICE approach to achieving my effect? Once this is complete I will post the full code for everyone who would like to achieve iOS browser effects.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, I have edited it, maybe it has a better quality now.

Comment: Lajos, I greatly do appreciate your help as I mentioned. I took a look at your code while I was finishing up my entire day of coding (atleast trying to... it wasn't pretty). I use Firefox and for some reason your example code did not work in fiddle.. Might have been a misunderstanding on my end. HOWEVER, I have created a Frankenstein bit of code, which I am sure is unoptimized however DOES create the desired functionality. Take a look here - http://jsfiddle.net/V7Apa/16/ - Test 1: Scroll down beyond the 120 mark, then scroll up. Test 2: Scroll to the very end. What do you think?

Comment: Test 1 is what I was referring to of having a 30 pixel UP "buffer" so the class wouldn't change so quickly. Basically, if the user scrolled down and then back up it wouldnt switch until they scrolled back up 30 pixels from any point. It's strange, but if you look at the new ios update this might turn into a standard if I can get it tweaked out.

Comment: I do not know what was not working. I have mentioned that your third task is unclear to me, so I might have solved something else of what you wanted. When you tested my code, have you seen the messages in the console? When you have scrolled on the bottom of your document, and then scrolled upwards by at least 30 pixels, it typed something on the console. Have you seen that? Also, can you describe your third requirement? I am afraid I cannot help you if you do not help me help you.